# loop through 2 files with beautifulsoup and print output to a single panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have 2 html files as follow

table - 3.html

```
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Quatermass 2</strong></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>1957</td>


    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Ghostbusters</strong></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>1985</td>
```

table - 4.html

```
    <table width='100%' border='0' cellpadding='0' class='blackbg textheadtitle'>
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'>Title</td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>Year</td>
                <table width='99%' border='0' cellpadding='1' class="normal">
        <tr>
            <td width='41%' align='left'><strong>Life of Brian</strong></td>
            <td width='10%' align='left'>1985</td>
```

I would like to extract the following panda dataframe from the files => row 0 and 1 from table - 3.html and row 2 from table - 4.html

```
           Title  Year
0   Quatermass 2  1957
1   Ghostbusters  1985
2  Life of Brian  1985
```

My python code looks as below with the inputfilename listing my 2 files.

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#input results
inputfilename = 'html_files.txt'


#read input postcodes
inputfile = open(inputfilename, 'rb')   #rb = read binary
html_pages = inputfile.readlines()

for page in html_pages:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
    titles = soup.find_all("td", {"width": "41%"}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Title$)'))

    titles_list = [each.text for each in titles ]

    #df = pd.DataFrame(titles_list, columns=['Title'])

    years = soup.find_all("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$'))
    year_list = [each.text for each in years ]

    d = {'Title':titles_list, 'Year':year_list}

    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)

    print(df)
```

The section below the loop were I call my beautiful soup function works to extract my data from one file into desired dataframe.However when I apply the loop and indent all my code is yielding  an empty dataframe as per below

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Title, Year]
Index: []
```

Can anyone help me loop through both files and produce data into a dataframe please?

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re


filenames = ['one.txt', 'two.txt']

value1 = []
value2 = []
for file_name in filenames:
    with open(file_name) as html_file:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_file, 'html.parser')
        for item in soup.findAll('td', attrs={'width': '41%'}, string=re.compile(r'^(?!Title$)')):
            value1.append(item.text)
        for item in soup.findAll("td", {"width": "10%"}, string=re.compile(r'^\d{4}$')):
            value2.append(item.text)
data = []
for item in zip(value1, value2):
    data.append(item)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Title', 'Year'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
           Title  Year
0   Quatermass 2  1957
1   Ghostbusters  1985
2  Life of Brian  1985
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: for saving it use `df.to_csv('output.csv')`